# Motion path using bezier curve

Tags: opengl

I have to create a motion path using bezier curve. On running the following program, I get the values along the control polygon that is supposed to be the curve for my motion path, I can check them via the "printf" statement, however I do not actually get the curve.

What have I done wrong and how may I solve it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <gl/glut.h>
#include <cstdio>



struct point
{
float x;
float y;
};

// simple linear interpolation between two points
void lirp(point& dest, const point& a, const point& b, const float t)
{
dest.x = a.x + (b.x - a.x)*t;
dest.y = a.y + (b.y - a.y)*t;
}

// evaluate a point on a bezier-curve. t goes from 0 to 1.0
void bezier(point &dest, const point& a, const point& b, const point& c, const point& d, const float t)
{
point ab, bc, cd, abbc, bccd;

lirp(ab, a, b, t);           // point between a and b
lirp(bc, b, c, t);           // point between b and c
lirp(cd, c, d, t);           // point between c and d
lirp(abbc, ab, bc, t);       // point between ab and bc
lirp(bccd, bc, cd, t);       // point between bc and cd
lirp(dest, abbc, bccd, t);   // point on the bezier-curve

}

void Draw() {
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
glPointSize(20);

point a = { 700, 100 };
point b = { 650, 20 };
point c = { 600, 180 };
point d = { 550, 100 };

for (int i = 0; i<1000; ++i)    //should plot 1000 points within the control polygons.
{
    point p;
    float t = static_cast<float>(i) / 999.0;
    bezier(p, a, b, c, d, t);
    float p_x = p.x;
    float p_y = p.y;
    printf("%f %f\n", p_x, p_y);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(p_x, p_y, 0.0);
    glEnd();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}

}

void Timer(int Unused)
{
glutPostRedisplay();
glutTimerFunc(20, Timer, 0);
}



void Init() {
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, -1.0, 1.0);
}

int main(int iArgc, char** cppArgv) {
glutInit(&iArgc, cppArgv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
glutInitWindowPosition(200, 100);
glutCreateWindow("Animation Test");
Init();
glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
Timer(0);
glutMainLoop();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: *lol* That bezier code comes from my old website: http://cubic.org/docs/bezier.htm What a blast from the past.

Comment: oh! thanks you for making me understand about the curve approximations. that was awesomely explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up a projection volume with `glOrtho()` which is only 1x1. If you want to see your curve (whose dimensions are in the hundreds of units), you'll need to expand that.

Also, don't `glutSwapBuffers()` until after your for-loop; otherwise you may only end up seeing half the points. You should also put `glBegin()`/`glEnd()` outside the loop.

Comment: okay, but what else may I use instead of glOrtho()? And the bezier function only returns the "x" and "y" coordinates of the curve; isn't it simply a 2D draw function?

Comment: `glOrtho` is fine. It's your arguments to `glOrtho` that are the problem.

Comment: Hurrah!! It worked. I wasn't very clear on the range of values that glOrtho accepts. Passing my windowsize dimensions into the right and top parameters did the trick! Thank you for explaining! :D

Comment: One more question: Since I am actually to create a motion path defined by the curve, how do I make it move one point at a time? I mean all the points get drawn as soon as the glVertex receives them. I tried the following: 

  bezier(p, a, b, c, d, t);
  
  float p_x = p.x;
  float p_y = p.y;
  printf("%f %f\n", p_x, p_y);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); // Clean the screen and the depth buffer
  glLoadIdentity();
  glVertex3f(p_x, p_y, 0.0);
 }

 glEnd();
 glutSwapBuffers();

but everytime I still get the full curve before reiteration rather than one point at a time.